# sqlalchemy orm | fastAPI querying + joining three tables to get parents and all children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, many-to-many, fastapi

I'm trying to make have a route in my fastAPI that gives back a list of all parents.`portfolios` and all the children or `stocks` that are associated with each of them PLUS the extra data that is in the association table (for that relationship).

The response is suppose to look somewhat like this

```py
[ { "parrent1_attr1": bla,
    "parrent1_attr2": bla,
    "children": [ {
        "child1_attr1": bla,
        "child1_attr2": bla},
        {"child2_attr1": bla,
         "child2_attr2": bla}]
},
etc...]
```

Right now the route that produces this looks like this:

```py
@router.get("/")
def get_all_portfolios(db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):

    results = db.query(models.Portfolio).options(joinedload(models.Portfolio.stocks)).all()
    return results
```

But this gives me the wrong result.

This results in this.

```py
[ { "parrent1_attr1": bla,
    "parrent1_attr2": bla,
    "children": [ {
          "association_table_attr1": bla
           "association_table_attr2": bla},]
```

So I get data from the association table back instead of from the children.

The models I have are here.

```py
class Portfolio(Base):
    __tablename__ = "portfolios"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    ...
    stocks = relationship("PortfolioStock", back_populates="portfolio")

class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stocks"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    ...
    portfolios = relationship("PortfolioStock", back_populates="stock")

class PortfolioStock(Base):
    __tablename__ = "portfolio_stocks"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stock_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("stocks.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    portfolio_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("portfolios.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    count = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    buy_in = Column(Float, nullable=True)
    stock = relationship("Stock", back_populates="portfolios")
    portfolio = relationship("Portfolio", back_populates="stocks")
```

Let me know if you need more information. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you include the code that prints the json-like data you've included?

Comment: Just added the route that the query is suppose to be executed in and returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody that is looking for an answer, here is how I fixed it.

I used the query from Ian that he mentioned above, (thank you a ton for that).
And then I just manually declared the structure I wanted to have.

The whole code looks like this

```py
    results = (
        db.query(models.Portfolio)
        .options(joinedload(models.Portfolio.stocks).joinedload(models.PortfolioStock.stock))
        .all()
    )
    result_list = []
    for portfolio in results:
        result_dict = portfolio.__dict__
        stock_list = []
        for sto in result_dict["stocks"]:
            sto_dict = sto.__dict__
            temp_sto = {}
            temp_sto = sto_dict["stock"]
            setattr(temp_sto, "buy_in", sto_dict["buy_in"])
            setattr(temp_sto, "count", sto_dict["count"])
            stock_list.append(temp_sto)
        result_dict["stocks"] = stock_list
        result_list.append(result_dict)
    return result_list
```

What I'm doing here is firstly declare an empty list where our final results will be stored and which will be returned.
Then we iterate over the query (because the query gives us a list back).
So we have each "SQL alchemy Model" now as `portfolio` in there.

Then we can convert this into a dictionary and assign it a new variable with `result_dict = portfolio.__dict__` The `__dict__` method converts the model into a Python dictionary that you can work with easily.

Since that `result_dict` contains a list of `PortfolioStock models` which is the association table model in. These are stored in the `stocks` key we have to iterate over them to get those values as well. And here we just repeat the process.

We convert the model into a dictionary with `__dict__` then make a new empty dictionary `temp_sto={}` and set it equal to the `stock` key which is the key that is linking the child to our association table. So now we have the child or `stock` we want to access. We can simply set our new empty dicitonary equal to that so we inherit all the information contained within.
And then we just have to add all other information from the association table that we might want which can be accessed via the dictionary we defined at the beginning of the for loop `sto_dict`.

Once we have this we append it to an empty list we have defined outside of this for loop but inside the `portfolio loop`.
Set the `result_dict["stocks"]` key (so basically the key where you want all children to be contained in) equal to that list we just appended all the dictionaries to and then append that dictionary to our `result_list`.
And last thing to do is just to return that list, and we're done.

I have provided an agnostic approach hopefully down below

```py
query = db.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.relationship).joinedload(AssociationTable.child).all()
result_list = []
for parent in query:
    parent_dict = parent.__dict__
    child_list = []
    for association in parent_dict["relationship_name"]:
        association_dict = association.__dict__
        temp_child_dict = {}
        temp_child_dict = association_dict["child"]
        setattr(temp_child_dict, "name_you_want", association_dict["key_of_value_you_want"])
        # repeat as many times as you need
        child_list.append(temp_child_dict)
    parent_dict["children"] = child_list
    result_list.append(parent_dict)
return result_list
```

I hope this helps you if you are in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I find it to be easier to give the association some name of its own because it is confusing but in this case `Portfolio.stocks` is actually a list of the association objects and NOT actual stocks.  You have to get those off the association object.  In my example below I go and get stock with `assoc.stock.id`.  That should not trigger another query because we used joinedload to pre-load it.  If the stock had a name we'd reference it with `assoc.stock.name`.

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    q = session.query(Portfolio).options(joinedload(Portfolio.stocks).joinedload(PortfolioStock.stock))
    for portfolio in q.all():
        print (f"Listing associated stocks for portfolio {portfolio.id}")
        for assoc in portfolio.stocks:
            print (f"    Buy in {assoc.buy_in}, count {assoc.count} and stock id {assoc.stock.id}")
```

The query looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT portfolios.id AS portfolios_id, stocks_1.id AS stocks_1_id, portfolio_stocks_1.id AS portfolio_stocks_1_id, portfolio_stocks_1.stock_id AS portfolio_stocks_1_stock_id, portfolio_stocks_1.portfolio_id AS portfolio_stocks_1_portfolio_id, portfolio_stocks_1.count AS portfolio_stocks_1_count, portfolio_stocks_1.buy_in AS portfolio_stocks_1_buy_in 
FROM portfolios LEFT OUTER JOIN portfolio_stocks AS portfolio_stocks_1 ON portfolios.id = portfolio_stocks_1.portfolio_id LEFT OUTER JOIN stocks AS stocks_1 ON stocks_1.id = portfolio_stocks_1.stock_id
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried it. It looks almost right. Thanks a ton already.
It now links the association table where the "child" table is suppose to go. Something like this 
[
    {
        parent info here
        "stocks": [
            {
                 Association table information here
                "stock": {
                               child info here
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: If I try to do `db.query(models.Portfolio).options(joinedload(models.PortfolioStock.stock)).all()` to basically "pull up" that stock table. It gives me an error message:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped attribute "PortfolioStock.stock" does not apply to any of the root entities in this query, e.g. mapped class Portfolio->portfolios. Please specify the full path from one of the root entities to the target attribute.` So not sure how to circumvent this.

Comment: Yeah you can't do that because you have to join across the association to get the stocks.  The `joinedload` just preloads the properties across the relationships.

Comment: Ah, so basically the solution you provided is the only way to get all of the information? Alright I guess I make that work then in the frontend. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks again a ton for the help you provided. I figured it our thanks to that <3